# Slide Div Content With jquery html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made Tabs. Each Tab contain one div. i want to slide div content from left to right with use of if else condition. But I checked with alert box. But it did not work. Here is my code.

```
$('.tabs').click(function() {
if ('.tabs :nth-child(even)')
    {
  alert("11111");
  $('.tab-content').hide("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  }, 1000);
  alert("222222");
  $('.tab-content').show("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  }, 1000);
  alert("3333333");} 
    else 
   {
     $('.tab-content').hide("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 1000);
  alert("777777");
  $('.tab-content').show("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 1000);
  alert("6666666");
  }
});
```

Comment: I've finxed problems in your code. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `click` event you are missing `$` and your `if` condition is wrong.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/8jwk1qpf/)

Here is a demo code to check even or odd index:

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  //do something different based on whether even or odd div
  if ($(this).is(':even')) {
    $(this).html('even');
  } else {
    $(this).html('odd');
  }
});
```

```html
   
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div>three</div>
<div>four</div>
```

**EDIT :** If you don't want to use odd even concept you can just `toggle`.One of the easiest bug free way is to do the way I have done in the fiddle.

**[YOUR FIDDLE UPDATED](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/ywbkcu63/1/)**

**EDIT 2 :** [**CHECK THIS OUT TO SHOW ONLY TARGET CONTENT**](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/ywbkcu63/3/)

Comment: I want to make that if i m on tab 3 and i m clicking on tab 2 it will slide from left. And id i m on tab 3 and i m clicking on tab 4 it will slide from right. I don't want to use Odd - Even concept. Exactly same for all tabs. for that should i do comparision ???

Comment: @Ashmi can you provide a fiddle for you problem.This solution only gives the error in your code.

Comment: But sometimes it not works in fiddle. it is working in browser.

Comment: But i want that when i click on the tab other tab content will hide. I can show only current tab content. example i m on tab 1 currently but when click tab 2 all the other tab's content will hide so i can only show tab 2 content

Comment: @Ashmi what do mean by hiding the content

Comment: I want that if i click on tab 3 all contents of other tab will hide. And only tab 3 content will show with animation like slide from left or right

Comment: Thank You @shubham. It is working. There was my mistake.